# IBM JRE on Mac?

Tags: java

For some uses such as communicating with Weblogic or WebSphere application servers from Windows or Unix, I have to use the IBM JRE.

Does such thing exist on Mac? and/or how can I do that (except for the obvious solution of not using a Mac to run these programs)?

Comment: Linux in a Virtual Box

Comment: Surely any JRE can communicate with other JRE as the same java runs on both (I maybe can understand Websphere as an IBM product requiring an IBM jre but on on a server) Weblogic is an Oracle product so why does it need an IBM JRE?

Comment: Hi,
I work for IBM, and today I saw IBM JAVA 1.8 for MAC, unfortunately I am not sure if this is for use outside IBM.